# convert join query into nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, time-and-attendance

how to convert this query into a nested query which uses where in condition?

SELECT schedule.subcode,attendance.usn,avg(attendance.ispresent)*100 as Attendance_Percentage
FROM schedule JOIN attendance ON schedule.sched_id=attendance.sched_id 
WHERE usn="4jc14is013" AND subcode="is530";

Comment: `HAVING AVG(ispresent) < 0.75`

Comment: Your database format is not in normal form. It should be two tables:  
`Persons(usn, name)` and `Presence(date, usn)`.  See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT usn, name, AVG(ispresent) attendance FROM table 
GROUP BY usn, name HAVING attendance < 0.75;
```

Comment: You forgot the GROUP BY clause